# Laravel 5.3 sometimes return different 404 page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, error-handling

I'm trying to understand why my 404 page is not loading if I try to go under public folders.

When I'm trying to go assets folder. I'm getting this 404 page.

[image]

Comment: Show the code and routes file which is showing this error. @Murat

Comment: Your document root should be set to your public folder.  You can't go under that folder, it's not public.  At this point, you aren't hitting Laravel's index file so there is no Laravel, hence no Laravel 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your views are placed inside `resources/view` folder.
When you run Laravel in your local PC or server, run it with administrative privileges (not a must be thing)

```
sudo php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

This is what I use in Linux. I think you are missing something here.